# Conformal energy and first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, computational-geometry, conformal-geometry

In my reference in mesh processing I came across the following equation

[image]

Where $\bf{I}$ is the first fundametal form of some surface patch $\bf{x}$, I don't know the exact meaning of the notation $\bf{x}_u$ *orthogonal* (I don't know how to do the symbol in the formula). I've tried to expand the expression, but I don't end up with anything.

My assumption was to write the rejection of $\bf{x}_u$ respect to $\bf{x}_v$, but it doesn't seem to lead me to anything... Any suggestion?

Comment: It would be good if you gave the full reference from where you got this expression.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8zX-2VRqBAkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=mesh+processing&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja5vux7NrdAhUQbcAKHZ2uDqAQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=mesh%20processing&f=false, Chapter 5, section 5.4

Comment: My guess is that $\cdot^\perp$ denotes a rotation by $\pi/2$ in the tangent plane, since we would then have $x_v -x_u^\perp = 0$ if and only if $x$ is conformal.

Comment: Regardless of what the $\perp$ notation exactly denotes, this "conformal energy" is a well-known quantity in geometry processing, and is more commonly written $\frac12 \int (\sigma_1-\sigma_2)^2\, dA$ where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of the Jacobian of $\bf x$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis and how does the equality follows?

Comment: If you use singular values, it's super easy, since the area density is $\sigma_1 \sigma_2,$ the Dirichlet energy density is $\frac12 (\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$ and the conformal energy density is $\frac12(\sigma_1 - \sigma_2)^2.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis can you please show it?